# How to run maven built class in command line

Tags: java

I have a class file build by maven. It is just one class with main method in it. The file situates under:

```
<projectRoot>/target/classes/com/myproject/client/MyClass.class
```

The class is in package:

```
com.myproject.client
```

The class has no dependency on other classes.

My question is that how can I run it using the "java" command line.

Many thanks.

Comment: Move to project root, run 

java -cp target/classes com.myorject.client.MyClass

will work.

Comment: This produces error "Error: Could not find or load main class com.myproject.client.MyClass"

Comment: Guess your MyClass does not have main() method in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
java -cp "<projectRoot>/target/classes" com.myproject.client.MyClass [optional arguments]
```

Comment: This produces error "Error: Could not find or load main class com.myproject.client.MyClass"

Comment: check two things: 1) <projectRoot>/target/classes/com/myproject/client/MyClass.class exists. 2) You have 'public static void main(...)' method defined in MyClass.java

Comment: Yes. Both of these are true.

Comment: are there any spaces in <projectRoot> ?

Comment: Make also sure that <prpojectRoot> is a full absolute path to your target directory and if you have spaces or special chars in it, quote the whole path as I've just provided in the answer's update.